# Python: Divide values in cell by max in each column

Tags: python, numpy

Is this an efficient or correct way to divide every cell in each column by the maximum value in that column within a table? Is there a better implementation (if this is correct)?
Note: All values >= 0

```
new_data = [];
for row in np.transpose(data)[1::]: #from 1 till end
    for elements in row:
        if sum(elements) != 0:
            new_data.append(elements/max(row));
        else:
            new_data.append(0);
new_data = np.transpose(new_data);
```

Now:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
A   2    1    4    0
B   3    8    2    0
C   2    3    0    0
D   5    5    3    0
E   6    3    3    0
```

Required:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
A  1/3  1/8  1     0  
B  1/2  1    1/2   0
C  1/3  3/8  0     0
D  5/6  5/8  3/4   0
E  1    3/8  3/4   0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you handle `0`? Like the last column? It should be `nan` in theory. (`sum(elements) != 0`, what if it is -2 -1 0 1 2? That should be result in -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1, right?)

```
In [138]:

A*1./np.max(A, axis=0)
Out[138]:
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.125     ,  1.        ,         nan],
       [ 0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.5       ,         nan],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.375     ,  0.        ,         nan],
       [ 0.83333333,  0.625     ,  0.75      ,         nan],
       [ 1.        ,  0.375     ,  0.75      ,         nan]])
```

We can leave the last column as it is.

```
In [141]:

np.where(np.max(A, axis=0)==0, A, A*1./np.max(A, axis=0))
Out[141]:
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.125     ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.375     ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.83333333,  0.625     ,  0.75      ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.375     ,  0.75      ,  0.        ]])
```

The correct way of doing it with a loop is:

```
for row in A.T:
    if max(row)>0:
        new_data.append([item*1./max(row) for item in row])
    else:
        new_data.append(row)
```

Comment: There isn't any value < 0. Made an assumption which I probably should have stated. I'd like nan to be replaced with 0. If all the values in a column = 0 then every value in that column = 0. Else, it's cell/max(in column)

Comment: Without numpy, you wouldn't be able to `.transpose()` in the first place :).

Comment: Fair enough. If I defined a transpose function/wrote one myself.

Answer (score 3):

Well , another way to do (with **numpy**):

```
import numpy as np
M / (M.max(axis=0) + np.spacing(0))
```

The trick is use a small or infinitesimal number "**np.spacing(0)** (in Python)" to avoid division 0/0. In MATLAB, for example is **eps**.

### Example:

[image: Array divided by max value per column avoiding division 0/0]

As a function will be:

[image: function1]

**But, what happens if we want a division by max value in each row?**

The key: *transpose* In Numpy: **.transpose()** or **.T**

Using the defined the previous array **M** and the function **fun1** will be:

1. Transpose Matrix M
2. Use **fun1**
3. Transpose the last array evaluated

[image: Using function1 to divide by max element in each row]